# Ubuntu for Android - I don't fully understand what it is

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

I read up on the Ubuntu for Android thing and I'm confused, Specifically on these topics:

- When you're away from your home computer what OS does your phone use?
- Is the OS literally only for when you connect the phone to the PC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phone will always be running Android as its base OS. When you dock it (the dock being plugged to a large screen, a keyboard and a mouse) the phone fires up a X session running Unity. When you remove the phone from the dock the X session closes and you are back to the Android touch interface.

Although this has not been discussed in the various videos released, there is no reference to a special behaviour when connecting the phone to a PC. Thus I would expect it to behave as usual, and simply mount the phone SD through MTP.